# Rock Paper Scissors Variables not being recognized and program ending in JAVA

Tags: java, variables, while-loop

Im a novice at programming and I have been writing a simple program to create a Rock Paper Scissors game that continues to show an error. While initiating/running this program, it seems to not recognize the variables Rock Paper and Scissors and goes straight to the else condition. Also, when I try parsing after

```
int exit = 4;
while (exit != userchoice){
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose wisely. Enter:\n 1 for Rock \n 2 for Paper "
        + "\n 3 for Scissors \n or 4 to Exit:\n");
```

The program just stops there so I am still having a hard time finding any other way. Also, how would this program be ended with the condition I am going with? I still do not understand how to end this loop as I thought with a simple final bracket it would end the loop once the condition is met which is in this case typing the number 4.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inString = null;
    int compchoice = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
    int userchoice = 0;
    int Rock = 1, Paper = 2, Scissors = 3;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            "Welcome to JanKenPo! It is You Vs. The Computer\n");

    int exit = 4;
    while (exit != userchoice){
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose wisely. Enter:\n 1 for Rock \n 2 for Paper "
            + "\n 3 for Scissors \n or 4 to Exit:\n");

    if (userchoice == Rock && compchoice == Paper) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paper covers Rock! You win this Round.");
            }             
    else if (userchoice == Rock && compchoice == Scissors){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rock crushes Scissors! You win this Round.");
            }        
    else if (userchoice == Scissors && compchoice == Paper){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Scissors cuts Paper! You win this round.");
            }
    else if (userchoice == Paper && compchoice == Rock){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paper Covers Rock! Computer wins this Round.");
            }
    else if (userchoice == Paper && compchoice == Scissors){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Scissors cuts Paper! Computer wins this Round.");
            }
    else if (userchoice == Scissors && compchoice == Rock){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rock crushes Scissors! Computer wins this Round.");
            }
    else if (userchoice == compchoice){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's a Tie! Both you and the computer chose the same object.");
        }
    else{
        exit = Integer.parseInt(inString);
        }
    }   
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good Bye!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
userChoice = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Right now, you are just completely ignoring the input and not setting `userChoice` :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to do the above mentioned as well as:
You do not need the Scanner as you are getting input from showInputDialog();
Add in your while loop body{

`String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);`

`userChoice = Integer.parseInt(input);`

`int compchoice = (int)(Math.random() * 3) +1;`

By adding +1 you will get output b/w 1-3 and you need to add this in while loop as computer needs to make a choice every time the loop runs.

Also remove the line from else block  `exit =Integer.parseInt(inString);`

Your program will terminate when the user will enter choice 4;